# Simplifying `if then` blocks

Tags: ruby

I have several instances of code that look like this:

```
if checkProperties(top_properties, payload) == false
   return false
end
```

`checkProperties` has only one return for `false` depending on some condition:

```
def checkProperties(properties, to_check)
   properties.each do |property|
      if to_check[property.to_s].nil? or to_check[property.to_s].blank?
         log_err("Something went wrong")
         return false
      end
    end
end
```

However I feel this can be simplified. Is it valid to just use the following?

```
return false unless checkProperties(top_properties, payload)
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: There is no method `blank?` in [tag:ruby] in the first place. It’s _rails_ and `#blank?` includes the check for `nil`.

Comment: Also please remove “ternary” from the title; the question has zero mentions of ternary (which is `condition ? truthy : falsey`.) Short form of `if`/`unless` is called “postfix notation.”

Comment: `or` is a control flow operator, you want `||`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t return from blocks in the first place. Use `break` instead:

```
def checkProperties(properties, to_check)
  properties.each_with_object(true) do |property, _|
    if to_check[property.to_s].to_s.empty?
      log_err("Something went wrong")
      break false
    end
  end
end
```

or use `any?` and/or `all?`:

```
def checkProperties(properties, to_check)
  (!properties.any? { |p| to_check[p.to_s].to_s.empty? }).tap do |good|
    log_err("Something went wrong") unless good
  end
end
```

---

To explicitly show what property was missing, use [`Enumerable#find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

```
def empty_property?(properties, to_check)
  !!(properties.find { |p| to_check[p.to_s].to_s.empty? }.tap do |prop|
    log_err("Property #{prop.inspect} was missing") unless prop.nil?
  end)
end
```

I also took a liberty to renamed a method to follow Ruby naming convention (snake case with a question mark on the end for methods returning `true`/`false`.)

Double bang trick is needed to produce `true`/`false` out of possible values returned from `find`: the missing property or `nil`.

Comment: Thanks - and then when I use i actually call it - would it be valid to use `return false unless checkProperties(top_properties, payload)`

Comment: Completely legit.

Comment: Ok. And another question, would the keyword return also stop it at that iteration i.e. why is break needed?

Comment: To simplify code a bit and to make it to read better I would go with the method named `empty_porerties?` and `return false if empty_properties?(...)`.

Comment: `break` is not needed but strongly suggested because Ruby has many different implementations and `return` basically plays dirty with a stack, while `break` does not. The latter might, or might not have any implication, but `break` is safer _and_ much easier for the GC to know what’s going on and do it’s job faster.

Comment: Cool - thansk for explaining. So in the above using `any` avoids me having to check for nil?

Comment: The code indeed checks for `nil`s, implicitly. Note I call `to_s` before calling `empty?`. `nil.to_s` is an empty string and this is how the code checks for nils.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182920/discussion-between-usermod2-and-aleksei-matiushkin).

Answer (score 1):

You can check with `all?` enumerator. This will return true only if all has values below:

```
def checkProperties(properties, to_check)
  properties.all? { |p| to_check[p.to_s] && !to_check[p.to_s].blank? }
end
```

If any of the `property` in `to_check` is nil/absent, `all?` will return false and stop iterating from there.

Comment: This is different from what OP checked _and_ this does not print log message.

Answer (score 1):

> Any other suggestions?

A custom error class would work:

```
class PropertyError < StandardError
end
```

You could raise it when encountering a missing property:

```
def check_properties(properties, to_check)
  properties.each do |property|
    raise PropertyError if to_check[property.to_s].blank?
  end
end
```

This would eliminate the need for conditionals and explicit returns, you'd just have to call:

```
def foo
  check_properties(top_properties, payload)

  # do something with top_properties / payload
end
```

And somewhere "above" you could handle the logging:

```
begin
  foo
rescue PropertyError
  log_err 'Something went wrong'
end
```

Of course, you can also store the missing property's name or other information in the exception to provide a more meaningful error / log message.